# python selenium webdriver is unable to locate elements with explicit wait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate making purchases on nike.com with python selenium, but my program always fails because of a common error - unable to locate element. Initially, I was trying to use `<driver>.find_element_by_xpath(<xpath>)`, but sometimes the elements were not available in time for them to be found, so I decided to use WebdriverWait:

```
try: 
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='placeorder']/div/div[1]/button")))
        #(driver.find_element("//button[text() = 'Place Order']"))
        print("found the button!")
except:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='payment']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/button")))
        #(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Continue To Order Review']"))
        print("found the alternate button")
```

I'm using a try/except block because the button that I need to complete the purchase is not always the same. In one case, it could be a button saying 'place order', or it could be a differently shaped button saying 'continue to order review.' Here they are:

[image: picture of continue to place order]

[[image: picture of continue to order review button1]

Unfortunately, in these cases, the button is still not clicked (or found), and the script throws a TimeoutException. How can I get around this type of error? I've been looking through similar people's errors, but I can't seem to find a solution that works.

Comment: so you've targeted those 'cases' (where the buttons can change) and the driver still doesn't locate them via the bit you have above?

Comment: @chrymxbrwn Right, with the snippet above, the driver is still unable to locate them. I've verified their respective xpaths as well

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Place Order']|//button[text()='Continue To Order Review']")))
```

You can use | as an or to find one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but this also returns the same error. Could this have anything to do with selenium? I've never been able to select these buttons, but other elements that I use the driver to interact with work sometimes, sometimes not.

Comment: It seems there might be an iframe. You have to switch to iframes to access them.

Comment: pipe is a nice trick.  Does it do the same thing as chaining them essentially or is the behavior different?

Comment: It's basically the equivalent of an OR.